# Handling unique case to untar and cd into the folder

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script to untar/unzip a compressed file and cd into it and then run another load script to load. Everything works fine expect when I have unique cases when the top level directory is just `/`. Does anyone know how I should handle this unique case?

To be more clear, I need to cd into myfile_01 and not the root directory.

```
tar -xvzf $fname
cd $(tar -tf $fname | grep -m3 /$)    #tar it and cd into it
loadIt                                #run load script
```

Unique case that would cause a problem:

```
[user@user my_directory]$ tar -tf myfile_01.tgz | grep -m3 /$
./                            # it will cause it to cd to top level directory instead of my_file01
./myfile_01/
```

Comment: So you basically want to `cd` into the first directory of your archive? What do you expect it to do if your archive contains at least 4 top-level directories?

Comment: that will not likely happen but i want to cd into the folder that gets extracted from the tar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the pattern of your script, can't you just remove the top level directory that is giving you trouble?

Using grep:

```
tar -tf myfile_01.tgz | grep -m3 /$ | grep --invert-match --extended-regexp '^\./$'
```

Using tail:

```
tar -tf myfile_01.tgz | grep -m3 /$ | tail -1
```